# How to see the create time of a MySql user?

Tags: mysql, database

How to see the create time of a MySql user?

I want to know the create time of a MySql user called "local".

Therefore, I have queried the `mysql.user` table, but that does not display the creation time for the user. Furthremore, there are no MySql logs in `/var/log`.

I need the information for doing forensics analysis on the system.

Is there any way to obtain the create time for MySql users?

Comment: I don't believe you can do this for historical records, but the `mysql.user` table is just MyISAM - so I fully expect you could add a timestamp column with `default` set to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: @wally - thanks, but this only helps me going forward, right? What is MyISAM?

Comment: Correct that it will only help going forward. MyISAM is one of the older (and more legacy) on-disk table formats that MySQL supports.  It has some major shortcomings (like table-level locking over row-level), but is still used for several core MySQL tables (like the users table).

Answer (score 0):

You would query the information_schema for the create_time of the table.

For instance:

```
SELECT create_time FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES   
WHERE table_schema = 'your_schema'   
AND table_name = 'your_table'
```

**Reference**: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html

Comment: This doesn't tell me when the MySql user was created?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you, I though you wanted it for the table, not the user itself

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the user creation date then you can add a timestamp column in mysql.user table and set it to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default. So next time when a user is created, you will get the timestamp.